# Change the template and CBV depending on the nuber of results in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a CBV that inherits from Listview.

I need:

1. If there is no element in the queryset, is empty, I need to show the
   template with a different message or another template
2. If there is just one element in the queryset I need to go(redirect)
   to the DetailView

Based on some previous answers that I received(on other questions) for 2, I think I need to overwrite get.

If I I fully change get, my concern is that, later, if change change behavior, can create issue(it has also pagination, context related code).

If I call `super()` and store get in a variable, how do I know/get the result of get_queryset ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution would be to override get_template_names method in your CBV.

```
class MyCBV(django.views.generic.TemplateView):
    ...
    def get_template_names(self):
        if not self.queryset.count():
            return ["custom_template1.html", ]
        elif self.queryset.count() == 1:
            return ["custom_template2.html", ]
        else:
            return ["default_template.html", ]
```

hope it helps. I think overriding get_template_names is better idea rather then get, since get does some other things which should be rewritten, so to stay DRY my advise would be to override get_template_names method.